# Is there any equivalent is there for 'sp_refreshview' in Azure Synapse Dedicated SQL Pool

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, sql-data-warehouse

Is there any equivalent is available for '**sp_refreshview**' in Azure Synapse Dedicated SQL Pool?

When i tried , it shows below error.
[image]

Since VIEWS WONT GET UPDATED AUTOMATICALLY, is there any other command or system stored procedure available in Azure Synapse Analytics's Dedicated SQL Pool other than 'ALTER VIEW' Approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`EXEC sys.sp_refreshsqlmodule 'dbo.YourViewName';`

See the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-refreshsqlmodule-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15&viewFallbackFrom=azure-sqldw-latest&WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-4020762).

Comment: Thanks GregGalloway, it worked!