# Create a stored procedure to recreate a view only when external table is modified

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-synapse

I am trying to write a stored procedure which will be checking create and modify dates of view (`sys.views`) and external table (`sys.external_tables`) and recreate the view when needed (so only on the last modified date).
And I am struggling a bit with writing as I am new to this.

So far I have:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE create_alter_view 
(
    @Name VARCHAR(50) = 'table_1'
)
AS 
BEGIN
    IF ( 0 <> (SELECT create_date, modify_date FROM sys.external_tables WHERE modify_date = MAX(modify_date)))
        BEGIN
        DECLARE @statement NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'CREATE OR ALTER VIEW ' + @Name + ' AS
        SELECT TOP (10) *
        FROM
        FROM [dataverse_progrescloud_unqff756b2e147e462a957b87128de15].[dbo].[progres_individual]
        ) AS [r]
'       
        EXEC sp_executesql @tsql = @statement;
    END
END
```

Would someone be kind to help with my logic and code here? I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Seems a terrible idea.

Comment: What is/isn't working about your current code?

Comment: Currently I am having a ` An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'BEGIN'. `error @DaleK

Comment: You IF statement needs to return a boolean.

Comment: @DaleK if I change my code like above I get another error: An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Comment: Your query doesn't return an int, so you can't compare it to 0. And you aren't restricting your query to the single table passed in... so your query is operating on ALL records in the external_tables table.

Comment: Start small, and build your query up, see what results the query returns and see if they are what you are expecting... then build from there.

Comment: okay, makes since, now i selected that one external table that i need. will see how to get the proper outcome. Thanks for all the help! @DaleK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of glaring errors in your procedure

- You are comparing `0` to two columns from a subquery, both of which are dates, which makes no sense at all. A subquery must select a single value
- The subquery itself doesn't make a huge amount of sense. You probably want to compare the `modify_date` of `sys.external_tables` and `sys.views`.
- The data types for object names is wrong.
- To re-create the view, you probably want a dynamic query that gets the definition and runs an `ALTER`.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE create_alter_view 
    @Name sysname = 'table_1'
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @definition nvarchar(max);

SELECT
  @definition = REPLACE(sm.definition, 'CREATE', 'ALTER')
FROM sys.views v
JOIN sys.sql_modules sm ON s.object_id = v.object_id
WHERE v.name = @Name
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies ed
    JOIN sys.external_tables et ON et.name = ed.referenced_entity_name
    WHERE ed.referencing_id = v.object_id
      AND et.modify_date > v.modify_date
);

IF @definition IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_executesql @definition;
END
```

**However, I recommend you do *not* use the above.** It is very brittle, as it's subject to you not having the word `CREATE` elsewhere in the view, and `sql_expression_dependencies` can also be problematic if you do not declare the schema explicitly.

It appears what you actually want is `sp_refreshsqlmodule`, which is designed to refresh views and procedures when the underlying tables have been changed.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE create_alter_view 
    @Name sysname = 'table_1'
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM sys.views v
    WHERE v.name = @Name
      AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies ed
        JOIN sys.external_tables et ON et.name = ed.referenced_entity_name
        WHERE ed.referencing_id = v.object_id
          AND et.modify_date > v.modify_date
    )
EXEC sp_refreshsqlmodule @Name;
```

Comment: thank you for such a detailed and well explained answer! I am aware of the sp_refreshsqlmodule, however I want to create views on the SQL serverless pool in Synapse which does not support either sp_refreshview nor sp_refreshsqlmodule so I was looking to automate the way of creating views when changes happen on the tables.

Comment: Are you sure `sp_refreshsqlmodule` is not available? The docs seem to say so https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-refreshsqlmodule-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16&viewFallbackFrom=azure-sqldw-latest as does this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69570694/14868997 can't test myself. I suggest if not that you post this question on [dba.se]